# Case study : Symmetry operation between VASP and Quantum espresso

Tags: vasp, quantum-espresso, symmetry

I am doing simple scf calculation to find similarities in the output of `VASP` and `QE`.
Recently, I encounter an interesting case. I took face-centred orthorhombic cell of Aluminium. Here is my POSCAR

```
Al
   4.05000000000000
     1.0300000000000000    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.9700000000000000    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000    1.0000000000000000
   Al
     4
Direct
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000
  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
  0.5000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
```

Here vasp code detects symmetry of orthorhomic cell with following symmetry operation (in `OUTCAR`)

```
 Subroutine INISYM returns: Found  8 space group operations
 (whereof  8 operations are pure point group operations),
 and found     4 'primitive' translations
```

Now using `QE` with following input

```
 &control
    calculation='relax'
    restart_mode='from_scratch',
    pseudo_dir ='.'
    outdir='./tmp/',
    prefix='al'
    tprnfor = .true.
    tstress = .true.
    disk_io='none'
 /
 &system
    ibrav=  0,A =4.05, nat=  4, ntyp= 1, ecutwfc =60,
    occupations='smearing', smearing='mv', degauss=0.02

 /
 &electrons
    diagonalization='cg'
    mixing_beta = 0.7
 /
&ions
ion_dynamics='bfgs'
/
CELL_PARAMETERS alat
1.03 0 0
0 0.97 0
0 0 1

ATOMIC_SPECIES
 Al  26.98 Al.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS alat
 Al 0.00 0.00 0.00
 Al 0.50 0.50 0.00
 Al 0.50 0.00 0.50
 Al 0.00 0.50 0.50
K_POINTS automatic
15 15 15  0 0 0
```

and output have shown following symmetry operation

```
      2 Sym. Ops. (no inversion) found
```

I have also test with `ibrav=8`, results are still same

Can somebody explain why `QE` is resulting only 2 point group operation in reality, it must have 8.

Comment: The solution of this problem is by replacing ATOMIC_POSITION alat to ATOMIC_POSITION crystal. Direct coordinate in CASE is equivalent to QE crystal not alat. we can close this question now

Comment: Did you vote to close it? If you found the answer, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

VASP input file is based on relative coordinates(`direct`) of the simulation box whereas in `QE` `alat` doesn't define relative coordinate, It only scale by lattice parameter. In `QE` relative coordinate is defined by atomic position tag `crystal`.
Correct input file for 8 different symmetry operations will be

````
 &control
    calculation='relax'
    restart_mode='from_scratch',
    pseudo_dir ='.'
    outdir='./tmp/',
    prefix='al'
    tprnfor = .true.
    tstress = .true.
    disk_io='none'
 /
 &system
    ibrav=  0,A =4.05, nat=  4, ntyp= 1, ecutwfc =60,
    occupations='smearing', smearing='mv', degauss=0.02

 /
 &electrons
    diagonalization='cg'
    mixing_beta = 0.7
 /
&ions
ion_dynamics='bfgs'
/
CELL_PARAMETERS alat
1.03 0 0
0 0.97 0
0 0 1

ATOMIC_SPECIES
 Al  26.98 Al.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
 Al 0.00 0.00 0.00
 Al 0.50 0.50 0.00
 Al 0.50 0.00 0.50
 Al 0.00 0.50 0.50
K_POINTS automatic
15 15 15  0 0 0
```
````

Comment: +1 and thanks for writing the answer when you figured it out, so that it can help future readers! I'd recommend not to put a green checkmark on your own answer, because unlike when you put a green checkmark on a different person's answer, the green checkmark doesn't have much of an effect other than discouraging others from writing alternative answers!